# Replacing Thumbnail Style in S3 using Paperclip (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

This is probably counter intuitive, however I'd like to either replace a currently existing paperclip attachment style or create a new one outside of the has_attached_file code. (thumbnails are stored in S3).

I'm using this great gem called SmartCropper that let's me take an image and crop around the focal point to the dimensions of my choice.

The code for it is something like this:

```
SmartCropper.from_file(banner.url(:medium)).smart_crop(350,630)
```

It's using a thumbnail I already cropped with paperclip (the medium sized banner), but I'd like this code to overwrite (in an S3 Bucket) another thumbnail style defined in banner like **cropped** or **thumb**.

Unfortunately it seems

```
banner.url(:medium) = SmartCropper.from_file(banner.url(:medium)).smart_crop(350,630)
```

is a terribly incorrect attempt at a solution. I also perused some of the S3 API for storing methods, which I did find, however none that would just accept a path and a file. The bucket system is fairly winding for paperclip, so it seems that the simple storing methods aren't the best option.

I tried researching if I could do this as a custom processor, but I wasn't able to really find what I wanted.

And everything I've done trying to change a thumbnail style to that new image has resulted in an S3 error.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paperclip methods 'url' and 'path' are just generate string according to your path settings. So if you have your file already uploaded, you can use following code to get path to your custom thumb:

```
banner.path(:my_custom_style) #this will be the path to save your custom thumb to
```

There are two important things here:

1. First, don't declare your style (i.e. :my_custom_style) neither in has_attached_file, nor in default Paperclip configuration. Otherwise if you ever run reprocessing without specifying exclusions you will lost your custom thumbs.
2. Use 'path' instead of 'url', because all you need is a path relative to your s3 bucket.

The next step is the easiest one. if you are using [aws-sdk](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby) gem, and have it configured with your credentials, then uploading file to a specified path is as simple as following:

```
s3 = AWS::S3.new
s3.buckets[YOUR_BUCKET].objects[path].write(binary_data)
```

Comment: It took a bit more tweaking from here but it was the general solution! Turns out I needed to remove the first / that is automatically in the path for my thumbnail to get the image to store in S3. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Serg can you add the comment above to the solution? Easy to miss this way.

Comment: Default configuration of [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb) doesn't add first slash to the result of `path` helper, so I don't think it should be part of the answer.